# Can data updated in same commit be read differently on different selects?

Tags: sql, database, transactions, database-administration

this is more of a theoretical question that occurred to me and not a situation i dealt with. Assuming we have a table:

```
Bank Account (
id      number,
balance number
)**
```

and two rows exist:

| ID | Balance |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.00 |
| 2 | 0.00 |

If a transaction performs the following code:

```
update Bank_Account
set balance = balance + 100
where id in (1,2);
commit;
```

Since a commit is not instantaneous, is it possible, after the previous transaction started executing, for these select statements, which start executing afterwards (but not necessarily after the first transaction finishes), to return different values?

```
select balance
from Bank_Account
where id = 1;

select balance
from Bank_Account
where id = 2;
```

E.g. one returns 0 and the other returns 100

If not, what prevents it from happening?

Database system: Any
Isolation level: Read Commited

Comment: Which DBMS are you talking about, and which isolation level are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to re produce you issue please elaborate it if you are using transaction it will be update and it will not give different response plz check in attached screen
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjTVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Changes you make to a table are visible to you only; once you run that `update` statement and select from that table you'll see 100 for both IDs. Everyone else will see 0.

Once you `commit`, everyone (literally *everyone*; you and the rest of users) will see 100 for both IDs.

You didn't specify database you use; this is link to Oracle 21 [Data concurrency and consistency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/cncpt/data-concurrency-and-consistency.html#GUID-E8CBA9C5-58E3-460F-A82A-850E0152E95C) which says

> The assurance that each user sees a consistent view of the data (data consistency), including visible changes made by the user's own transactions and committed transactions of other users

Have a look at that document for more info and/or search for similar document related to database you use.